# Problem controlling LEDs

Tags: gpio, python

I recently bought a Raspberry Pi 3 model B because I started learning Python in the University and I love the idea of making robots.

I started with the babis though: Controlling LEDs, and this came out from my mind (I used Python 3):

```
print('ok')
import sys
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(22,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(27,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(17 , False)
GPIO.output(22 , False)
GPIO.output(27 , False)
while True:
    color = input('insert color: ')
    state = input('insert state: ')
    if color=='red':
        color=17
    if color=='yellow':
        color=22
    if color=='blue':
        color=27
    if state=='on':
        state=True
    if state=='off':
        state=False
    GPIO.output(color , state)
    print('Done!')
    if GPIO.output(17 , True) and GPIO.output(22 , True) and GPIO.output(27 , True):
        time.sleep(.5)
        GPIO.output(17 , False)
        GPIO.output(22 , False)
        GPIO.output(27 , False)
        for x in range(0,7):
            GPIO.output(27 , False)
            GPIO.output(17 , True)
            time.sleep(.5)
            GPIO.output(17 , False)
            GPIO.output(22 , True)
            time.sleep(.5)
            GPIO.output(22 , False)
            GPIO.output(27 , True)
            time.sleep(.5)
```

So, this program does only two easy things:

1. Controlling LEDs
2. Doing a good looking "light-show" after all the lights were turned on.

The first part works well.
But the second one:

```
if GPIO.output(17 , True) and GPIO.output(22 , True) and GPIO.output(27 , True):
        time.sleep(.5)
        GPIO.output(17 , False)
        GPIO.output(22 , False)
        GPIO.output(27 , False)
        for x in range(0,7):
            GPIO.output(27 , False)
            GPIO.output(17 , True)
            time.sleep(.5)
            GPIO.output(17 , False)
            GPIO.output(22 , True)
            time.sleep(.5)
            GPIO.output(22 , False)
            GPIO.output(27 , True)
            time.sleep(.5)
```

just seems non-existent

So I ran a script, only without the first part and it worked!

Could you tell me why I'm having this issue?

Answer (score 3):

The command `GPIO.output(X , True)` unconditionally sets GPIO X high.  It does not return any meaningful status.

That means that the line

```
if GPIO.output(17 , True) and GPIO.output(22 , True) and GPIO.output(27 , True):
```

does nothing useful.

Comment: More specifically, I believe `GPIO.output` returns the special value `None` in Python terms, which should evaluate to `false`.